# How to filter JSON response in XCODE?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

situation:
I have a JSON response parsed via SwiftyJSON. And I'm populating table cells with the data. Everything is cool, but now I need to remove some dictionaries from my JSON, and it doesn't let me do that in an any way (loops or other conditions).

Example of received JSON:

```
{"post-comments" : [
              {
                "post" : "new",
                "_id" : "1",
              },
              {
                "post" : "new",
                "_id" : "2",
              },
              {
                "post" : "post with title",
                "_id" : "23",
              },
              {
                "post" : "new",
                "_id" : "29",
              },
              {
                "post" : "post with title",
                "_id" : "90",
              },
              {
                "post" : "post with title",
                "_id" : "33",
              }
            ]
```

}

I'm tryin to get rid of some dictionaries, lets say if "post" === "new" - I need to remove them from my JSON and continue populate my cells with left data.

Completely stuck.. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

here is the complete tableviewcontroller:

```
        class TableViewContr: UITableViewController {

        let Comments : String = "http://localhost:3000/api/comments/"

        var json : JSON = JSON.null

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            getPostComments(Comments)

        }

        func getPostComments(getcomments : String) {

            Alamofire.request(.GET, getcomments).responseJSON {
                response in

                guard let data = response.result.value else {
                    return
                }

                self.json = JSON(data)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            switch self.json["post-comments"].type {

            case Type.Array:
                return self.json["post-comments"].count

            default:
                return 1

            }
        }

        func populateFields(cell: TableViewContrCell, index: Int) {

            guard let comment = self.json["post-comments"][index]["post"].string else {
                return
            }
            cell.commentContent!.text = comment

        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewContrCell

            populateFields(cell, index: indexPath.row)

            return cell
        }


    }
```

Comment: how r populating the cells plz add some code.

Comment: Parse JSON dictionary into custom objects (classes/structs). Don't pass dictionary around. Dictionaries are low level and working with them is hard and the code is unreadable.

Comment: why do you minus the question? finding this easy - make an advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach to parse and filter the JSON data before reloading the table view.

`comments` is the data source array containing the `post-comments` dictionaries

```
class TableViewContr: UITableViewController {

  let commentURL : String = "http://localhost:3000/api/comments/"

  var comments = [[String:String]]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getPostComments(commentURL)
  }

  func getPostComments(getcomments : String) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, getcomments).responseJSON {
      response in

      guard let data = response.result.value else { return }

      let jsonData = JSON(data)
      let postComments = jsonData["post-comments"].arrayObject as! [[String:String]]
      self.comments = postComments.filter{$0["post"] != "new"}
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewContrCell

    let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
    cell.commentContent!.text = comment["post"]!

    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, you are a superstar, the code actually works whenever JSON has the same pattern. And I'm dumb, coz I did a mistake with brackets when created sample json :( corrected it

Comment: so it basically crashes on:
            let postComments = jsonData["post-comments"].arrayObject! as! [[String:String]]
saying: fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C

Comment: I don't use Alamofire, so I don't know what kind of data types are returned. The exclamation mark after `arrayObject` is redundant, the forced downcast unwraps the array anyway. Not every type is supposed to have a trailing exclamation / question mark.

Comment: Would you suggest something different to alamofire?

Comment: No, Alamofire has a good reputation, but I'm afraid I can't help with that type issue. The error message states that there is a (Objective-C) type which cannot be exposed to Swift

Comment: there is something todo with "as! [[String:String]]

the actual returned data from "let postComments = jsonData["post-comments"].arrayObject!"

[{
    "_id" = 56d0246b6bb9b2bf056e9d8e;
    post = 56cb232615d3eeed576e5107;
}, {
    "_id" = 56d024a36bb9b2bf056e9d8f;
    post = 56cb232615d3eeed576e5107;
}]
weird structure with semicolons and no quotes